# Independent test of residuals, absolute member equal zero

Tags: fitting

Does Mathematica offer any test for confirm independence of residuals? except DurbinWatsonD. And I would like to ask how to make some test in regress function which tests absolute member equal zero. I did it for parts, cause I could't find any easier way. Thx

Comment: It would be helpful to have a concrete example in Mathematica text input.

Comment: I have these residuals,e={-0.184275, 0.87173, 0.927734, 0.87173, -1.14694, -0.184275, \
-0.12827, -1.12827, -1.07227, 1.87173, -0.184275, -1.09093}  I need to makework this command [#n-#(n-1) &,e ] for sign test where count possitive sign,

Comment: Then I have this regress function -0.00240734 + 1.01867 x, where x are these values {10, 8, 5, 8, 7, 10, 7, 6, 3, 9, 10, 4} I need to test that absolute memeber can be equal zero

Answer (score 4):

The answer is a definite "No" but not just for *Mathematica*.  No test from any package *confirms* independence of residuals.  You can certainly look for evidence of departures from independence but not confirm independence.

But let's suppose that's just me being too picky.  Your data (constructed from the information you place in the comments) consists of all integers:

```
{{10, 10}, {8, 9}, {5, 6}, {8, 9}, {7, 6}, {10, 10}, {7, 7},
{6, 5}, {3, 2}, {9, 11}, {10, 10}, {4, 3}}
```

Most tests of independence of residuals in a regression assume some continuous error distribution (usually a normal distribution).  You would need to describe the data generation process that results in all integer values.  This could be due to rounding to the nearest integer or maybe the values you have are counts.  In short, more information is needed.  (And while I'm on a roll, unless the departures are very, very evident, then with just 12 sample points it is unlikely that departures might be found.)

Comment: Thank you, so I use that test with possitive marks, but I need to make work this equation with hashtags [#n-#(n-1) &,e ], . Do I need to use any command?

Comment: @JimBaldwin continue your sermons...we all benefit +1 :)

Comment: Before using any equations or hashtags you need to describe how the integer data are generated.  For example, if the dependent variables are  counts and then maybe a Poisson model is a possibility.  Then one might be able to construct a test for independence of the counts.  Testing for independence (or lack thereof) requires a model first and only then does a testing procedure follow.